# Which answer to a negative question is called positive?

Tags: terminology

In the following (toy) dialogs which answers are positive/negative (I really need to know)?

Q: Won't you marry me?
A: Yes, I will.

Q: Won't you marry me?
A: Yes, I will not

Q: Won't you marry me?
A: No, I will.

Q: Won't you marry me?
A: No, I will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive answers:

"I will", "Yes, I will", or "Yes."

Negative answers:

"I will not", "No, I will not", or  "No."

In this context,  "yes" or "no" are only sightly ambiguous. You can always ask for clarification, but usually it means what it would if someone said "will you" instead of "won't you."

Typically, an English speaker wouldn't say "No, I will" or "Yes, I won't", except in an attempt to be funny, or if the phrasing of the question was particularly confusing.

Comment: Also: No, I won't.

Comment: Ambiguous? What do you mean?

Comment: Ambiguous means that the meaning is not completely clear. In this case, it means that even though answering "yes" to such a question usually means "yes, I will", there is a small possibility that they actually meant they would not. In practice, nobody would actually do that unless they were trying to be funny or confusing, though.

Comment: Well, for me, there is no ambiguity in the answer. It is the question in the negative interrogative that is asked when the person asking the question is not expecting a positive answer. "Won't  you go with me?" implies the person is doubtful about a yes.

Answer (score 2):

Negative interrogatives and their tags:

Q: Won't you marry me? A: Yes, I will. [positive]

Q: Won't you marry me? A: No, I will not. or more usual: No, I won't [negative].

For negative interrogatives, the tag answer is the same as for the negative and positive one sees in **in a regular interrogative question.**

Will you marry me. A: Yes, I will. [positive]
Will you marry me? A: No, I won't. [negative]

The trick is to remove the negative interrogative, and use a regular question. The answer there will also fit a negative interrogative. That's how you can make it clear to yourself.

The negative interrogative is used when the speaker has doubts about a positive answer.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of questions—and the "correct" answers to them—are a problem in many languages. Many a conversation included exchanges like, "Yes you will, or yes you won't?"

That said, the question of whether someone would marry someone is sort of a set phrase that is usually put as

> **Will you** marry me?

(Source: practically any romantic movie or movie that includes a romantic sub-plot.)

Putting the question in positive is the best way to avoid misunderstandings.

The question of how a certain answer would be categorized is one I cannot pretend to be able to answer because categorizations (in any type of academic inquiry) are something that different specialists will have different opinions on.

Comment: What about negative interrogative?